# Is it possible to make an MS access 2007 code patch file?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I've been asked to make some changes to an access app, which looks easy enough to do. The data and the code reside in one file. The trouble is while I'm working on a copy of the file from some point in time the production file keeps changing, the plant operates 24/7. I'll need to make a patch to quickly apply to the production file so they can do an immediate switchover without shutting things down.

Is it possible to make a code patch this way in access, so I don't have to type my changes in all over again?

Otherwise, how can I best split the code and the data schema from the data, so I can work on as much code as possible that is independent of the data growth?

Thanks.

Comment: *The data and the code reside in one file.* This a an important mistake. First split the file into front-end (code etc) and back-end (data). Link the back-end files. Develop a new version of the code while your people continue to work away happily. Each user should have a front-end copy locally while the back-end resides on the server. There are wizards to split Access files.

Comment: Well, in the defense of the original author, it was built over 15 years ago for access 97 and its lifetime has exceeded expectations...

Comment: @Fionnuala thanks for the suggestion, if there are wizards to do this then I'll be able to do this once for a test version, and again very quickly during deployment which should get me off to the races.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the wizard that splits a single access file into a front end and back end file. Now I can update the front end file whenever I want to without losing the latest data.

In my case, I had to hold the shift key when opening the database to bypass the macro hiding the menus from the production users.

[image]